# What is the minimum software I require to set up a 'distributed' windows network?

Tags: networking, active-directory, windows

I need to set up a smallish windows network at the office.  I want the email profile in outlook connected to the login account like in a corporate network and each user needs to be able to hotdesk ie log in to their account on any pc in the office.

What is the mimimum set of software required to do this in Windows?

Comment: What email server are you using?

Comment: exchange but if I wanted to use zafara open source system will windows server AD be compatible?

Comment: Isn't the Outlook profile included in roaming profiles?

Comment: does that mean outlook running on an (AD?) roaming profiles basis will be compatible with Zafara?

Comment: @John Gardeniers, yes your outlook profile would be part of your roaming profile.  I was wondering about what email server he wanted because I was trying to decide if you could get away with a Linux+Samba solution and avoid having to pay for Windows Server.  If exchange is required then there really isn't much point mentioning a linux-based setup.

Comment: @Zoredache, if the outlook profile roams with the user then it shouldn't matter what the mail server is, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @John Gardeniers, yes that is correct.

Comment: Be careful: the Outlook *settings* are included in the roaming user profile, but its local storage (.PST files) usually *isn't*. If you don't use Exchange and have Outlook connect via POP3/SMTP to some other mail server, you'll need to move your PSTs from the default location and/or put them on a network share, otherwise you won't be able to access them from another workstation. And don't even try to share the same PST between different users: this is totally unsupported and unrealiable.

Comment: Exchange is definitely the best solution here; you not only get centralized mail storage, but also quite powerful workgroup and collaboration features (mailbox sharing, calendar sharing, meetings, address books, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides Windows 7 Business and Office 2007 for each client, you will need at least one server runing Windows Server 2008 (R2) and Exchange Server 2007 or 2010. You should consider Small Business Server, which includes both at a fraction of the cost of the two products and is specifically designed for small office networks.

Answer (score 1):

- A single server running SBS, configured with Active Directory, DNS, User Profile shares, and Exchange.
- Enough CALs for the total number of users/machines in the environment.
- All workstations running a business/pro edition of Windows capable of joining a domain.
- MS Office License for each workstation.

Possibly optional but recommended:

- A locally attached tape deck on the server with an NTBackup job capturing the server at minimum once a week
- Gigabit networking to the desktop to support full roaming profiles